# NO .csproj file in my asp.net core project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, csproj

I am doing c# programming course (building ASP.NET Core application) right now that is almost 1year old. The guy created web API application and class libraries and in those projects there was project.JSON files. I know that instead of the project.json file there is a .csproj file now but when I create my own project in VS 2017 asp.net core there is no such a file like .csproj. I need to set dependencies but I don't know how without.csproj file. Where can I find this file?

Comment: There is a folder that has the same name as your project, inside that folder should be your `.csproj` . if it's not there... i really can't help

Comment: Right click on the project in the `Solution Explorer` and then click on `Edit Project File`.

Answer (score 16):

Visual Studio doesn't display the file since the project itself *is* the csproj file.

You can right-click on it and select the `Edit …` action to edit the csproj file. You can also use the NuGet package manager to edit dependencies.

Previously (VS 2015), the project that VS used was an `.xproj` file and the `project.json` was displayed because it was "part of" that project.

Answer (score 6):

As @Martin said in his answer

> Visual Studio doesn't display the file since the project itself is the
> csproj file.

In case the `Edit` is not shown when you right-click on the project in the Solution explorer,you can:

1. Right Click on the project in the Solution Explorer. `Unload Project`
2. Right Click on the project in the Solution Explorer. `Edit ProjectName.csproj`
3. Edit what you want and save
4. Right Click on the project in the Solution Explorer. `Reload Project`

Answer (score 0):

File > Add > New Project (while your Solution .sln is selected)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `.csproj` or `.vbproj` file by the following ways:

1. Go to the project folder. Inside this folder, there is another folder which has the same name as the project. The `.csproj` or `.vbproj` file can be found inside this folder. `For example: C:\\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj`
2. Right click the project in Visual Studio Solution Explorer. You can see the option `Edit project file`. Using this option will open the project file inside Visual Studio editor.
3. Right click the project in Visual Studio Solution Explorer. Select `Unload Project`. Right click the project again in the Solution Explorer. You can see the Edit Project_Name.csproj file option. Using this option will open the project file inside Visual Studio editor. After editing reload the project in Solution Explorer.